# How can I get the following arc-shaped dynamically color changing animation for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-animation, android-canvas

I am trying to get something like this:

[image]

I need to continuously change the color of each arc sequentially to give a 'wave' like feel to it.
I don't know whether I should use Canvas to draw the entire animation or use drawable resource files.

Can anyone please suggest which would be better and why? Also , if you can link a similar looking animation which can be used as reference for this then that would be great too! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define the drawable file. The root node element can be animation-list

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_s1"
        android:duration="400" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_s2"
        android:duration="400" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_s3"
        android:duration="400" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_s4"
        android:duration="400" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_volume_s5"
        android:duration="400" />

</animation-list>
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer explains how I could animate the color change if my arcs are drawable files . But , i can't find a single resource which says drawing a curved line is possible with a drawable. All online resources just point to Canvas if just a curved line is required.